# How to edit a todo in a todo list without hooks and redux

Tags: reactjs

I have been stuck on this for days reading up on tutorials and articles but can not figure this out. Whenever I click on the pencil icon, I want it to edit the current do to. I have 4 components, the form (searchbar where i add todo), the app.js, the todoList, and a todo.js component. I am keeping all the state in the app and state in the form to keep track of the terms I am entering.

I am thinking I would need to create an editTodo method in the app and pass it down as a prop to the list and then the todoItem. Most tutorials or help online uses hooks or redux but I am learning vanilla React first. I am not asking for the answer directly but rather the steps or thought process to implement editing a todo item in the todolist. I am not sure even if my todo app is correct in the places where I am keeping state. I may get slack for asking.. but I do not know what else to do. Here is my code..

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    todos: []
  }
  
   addTodo = (todo) => {
      const newToDos = [...this.state.todos, todo];
      this.setState({
        todos: newToDos
      });
      
    };
  
    deleteTodo = (id) => {
      const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => {
        return todo.id !== id;
      });

      this.setState({
        todos: updatedTodos
      });
    }

    editTodo = (id, newValue) => {
      
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
          <Form addTodo={this.addTodo} />
          </div>
            
        </div>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
        <ToDoList 
          todos={this.state.todos} 
          deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo} 
          editingTodo={this.state.editingTodo}/>
        </div>
            
        </div>    
      </div>
      
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
const ToDoList = ({todos, deleteTodo, editingTodo}) => {
    
    const renderedList = todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group" key={todo.id}>
                <ToDoItem todo={todo} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} editingTodo={editingTodo}/>
            </ul>
            )
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {renderedList}
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default ToDoList;
```

```
const ToDoItem = ({todo, deleteTodo}) => {
    
    return (
        <div>
        <li style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} className="list-group-item m-3">
            {todo.text}
            
            <span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon 
                    icon={faPencilAlt} 
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}   
                />
                <FontAwesomeIcon 
                    icon={faTrash} 
                    style={{ marginLeft: '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    onClick={ () => deleteTodo(todo.id)}   
                />
            </span>
                                    
        </li>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

I don't think the form component is relevant here as I am trying to edit a todo item so will not include it here. If I do need to include it, let me know. It may not look like I have tried to implement this functionality, but either I could not find what I was looking for, understand the code, or just do not know how to implement it.

Update:

I added an isEditing field in the form component to my todo items so that maybe it can help me know if an item is being editing or not. I also redid the editTodo method.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    state = { term: ''};

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addTodo({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            text: this.state.term,
            isEditing: false
        });

        this.setState({
            term: ''
        });
    }
```

```
editTodo = (id, newValue) => {
      const editedTodos = [...this.state.todos].map((todo) => {
        if(todo.id === id) {
          todo.isEditing = true;
          todo.text = newValue;
        }
        return todo.text;     
      });

      this.setState({
        todos: [...this.state.todos, editedTodos]
      });
    }
```

I also passed that method down to the todoList and then to the todoItem like so

```
const ToDoItem = ({todo, deleteTodo, editTodo}) => {
    const renderContent = () => {
        if(todo.isEditing) {
            return <input type='text' />
        } else {
            return <span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon 
                    icon={faPencilAlt} 
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    onClick={ () => editTodo(todo.id, 'new value')}   
                />
                <FontAwesomeIcon 
                    icon={faTrash} 
                    style={{ marginLeft: '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    onClick={ () => deleteTodo(todo.id)}   
                />
                </span>
            }     
        }
    
    return (
            <div>
              <li style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space between'}} className="list-group-item m-3">
                {{!todo.isEditing ? todo.text : ''}}
                {renderContent()}
              </li>
           </div>
    );
}
```

So whenever I click on the the edit icon, it successfully shows 'new value' but now also adds an extra todo item which is blank. I figured out how to add the input field so that it shows also. I am accepting the answer Brian provided since it was the most helpful in a lot of ways but have not completed the functionality for editing a todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am thinking I would need to create an editTodo method in the app and pass it down as a prop to the list and then the todoItem.

This is exactly what you need to do. And yet:

1. `editTodo` method has no logic in it.
2. `ToDoList` component receives `editingTodo` method as a prop instead of defined `editTodo`.
3. You are indeed passing the `editingTodo` futher down to `ToDoItem` but you are not utilising it there `const ToDoItem = ({todo, deleteTodo}) => ...`
4. You don't have an `onClick` listener on the pencil icon, so nothing can happen.
5. I don't know how you are planning on doing the editing (modal window with a form, or replacing the text with an input field), either way the bottom line is that you need to trigger your pencil onClick listener with `() => editTodo(id, newText)`.

My recommendation would be - address all 5 points above and for now just hardcode the new value, just to test it out: `() => editTodo(id, 'updated value!')` and check that everything works. You can worry about getting the real value in there as your next step.

Comment: Where would I put or how do I use an input field to do the editing? In the app component?

Comment: Like I said, this is the next step. Get the hardcoded value changing first and test it.

Comment: I have modified my code and whenever I click on edit icon, I can see 'new value' render on the page. However I have two problems: It adds an extra todo item on the list, and the input text field is not showing up.

Comment: There must be thousands of free tutorials and courses on how to do these basic operations. React doesn't exactly have the shallowest learning curve, so you aren't doing yourself any favours by not following them.

Comment: Your absolutely right, I figured the rendering part out to where when I click on the edit icon it shows an input field. But, at the same time, it is still adding on an additional <li>. That, I can not figure out.